# Access controllers/views without login YII2 Advance

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am looking to access any specific controller without login in Yii2 advance version.

Access all the action - View, Index etc... let me know how I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you try something? Tell me, why we have to code for you?

Comment: You can guide me as I am trying to add action in my common/main.php 

'as beforeRequest' => [  //if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error','sheets'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],

This sheet action I want to access without login

Comment: add your code into the question not in the comment

Answer (score 1):

You can allow guest users to access action by adding this to rules.

```
[
    'allow' => true,
    'actions' => ['sheets'],
    'roles' => ['?'],
],
```